# Refreshing an image to show changes after it has been saved/modified

Tags: jquery

I'm using [jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) and have written a dynamic way of saving the cropped image without changing the page. Basically I write the new cropped profile picture to the same filename as previously, and load it to a div. However what happens instead is the old image remains because it assumes its the same image. Its not until I refresh the page and see the new file loaded again that i can see the changes.

Is there a function to force a refresh on an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a `?123` at the end of the `src` attribute of the image. 123 is a random number generated everytime you update the image.

`$('.my-img').attr('src',$('.my-img').attr('src')+'?' + ((Math.random() * 1e6) | 0));`